# Regular Expression for IP subnet with exclusion

Tags: regex

I am trying to set up an XML config file for TACACS. I am not the best at REGEX.

Essentially you can specify a group of clients. They make this easy to do if you want to include a whole subnet with:

```
      <Client>192.168.100.*</Client>
```

The problem I am running into is that I want to do different things for different clients (firewalls). For example, I want to say all clients in subnet 192.168.100.* EXCEPT for 192.168.100.127.

I immediately noticed a couple of problems.

192.168.100.[1-9][0-9] should cover 192.168.100.10-99 but grabs triple digit IPs in the last octet as well. Like 192.168.100.101 because it matches the 10 in 101. Same problem for 192.168.100.[1-9] as it grabs the first digit.

How do I force it to only grab one or two digits?

As for the exclusion I tried: 192.168.100.1[0-9][^7] It managed to not grab 192.168.100.127 but grabbed 192.168.100.11 as well when it should only be checking 100-199.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the regex for ip:

```
^(([01]?[0-9]?[0-9]|2([0-4][0-9]|5[0-5]))\.){3}([01]?[0-9]?[0-9]|2([0-4][0-9]|5[0-5]))$
```

and add a negative lookahead before the last part of ip:

```
^(([01]?[0-9]?[0-9]|2([0-4][0-9]|5[0-5]))\.){3}(?!127)([01]?[0-9]?[0-9]|2([0-4][0-9]|5[0-5]))$
//                                      here __^^^^^^^
```

For your specific address:

```
^192.168.100.(?!127)([01]?[0-9]?[0-9]|2([0-4][0-9]|5[0-5]))$
```

This will accept all the range `192.168.100.0` to `192.168.100.255` except `192.168.100.127`

Comment: Toto that works except for IPs ending in the 200-255 range testing it on http://regexr.com/

Comment: `192.168.100.(?!127)(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)`

Looks like it was just the order for the 4th octet. Working 100% now. Thank you @Toto

Comment: @user2998266: Strange, it works for me, using perl. But if it works for you when exchange the order, that's cool.

Answer (score 0):

Will [this](https://regex101.com/r/hNXmE3/3) work for you? `((?:2[0-5][0-5]|1\d\d|\d{1,2})\.(?:2[0-5][0-5]|1\d\d|\d{1,2})\.(?:2[0-5][0-5]|1\d\d|\d{1,2})\.(?:2[0-5][0-5]|1[^2][^7]|\d{1,2}))$`

Comment: What about: `249.249.249.249`

Comment: That does appear to grab everything from 192.168.100.1 to 255. Where in the last octet of the expression would I put the [^] to stop from grabbing any particular IP?

Comment: now it allows all IP adresses that are valid and don't end with 127

Comment: That doesn't accept ips that end with `.126` or `.117`

Comment: Oh true let me fix that

Answer (score 0):

Add a word boundary `\b` to the end of the IP, eg:

```
192.168.100.[1-9][0-9]\b
```

The word boundary, which doesn't consume any input, asserts that there *isn't* another digit.

For the "not 127" example, use this:

```
192.168.100.1[0-9][^7<]
```

Because `[^7]` will also match a following open bracket.